# Words for closing

Tags: words

In English, we use the word "close" liberally and loosely. But Japanese requires more specificity. Besides the difference between 閉じる and 閉める that confuses native English speakers, there are are also 閉校, 閉園, 閉館, etc. Focusing on the latter issue, how and to what extent are such two-character words used? I believe one or more may be heard in everyday conversation; but are my examples (and others, if they exist) more commonly found in newspapers, documentaries, etc.?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32640/

Comment: Related: [Closed: 休〜 vs. 閉〜](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41845/78).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

閉園, 閉館 and 閉店 are all very common, and they are chosen according to the type or name of the facility:

- **閉園**: open-air (amusement) park, zoo, garden
- **閉館**: (indoor) department store, shopping mall, museum, dome stadium
- **閉店**: shop, restaurants, supermarket

In formal announcements from facilities, these compounds are used nearly 100% of the time. Newspaper articles usually use them, too. In everyday conversation, both 閉まる and these compounds are common. Everyone except for small children understands these terms and use in day-to-day conversation. 閉場 is relatively less common but used in the same way. Note that they can be used to indicate both the nightly closing and the permanent shutdown.

閉校 is less common, and it normally refers to the permanent shutdown of a school.